# Why do pictures of fire come out purple?

Tags: color, fire

When I'm taking pictures of my log fire the flames and embers come out in rich shades of purple rather than red. I've tweaked everything I can on my camera; white balance, metering, ISO, exposure, but nothing makes a difference.

I'm assuming there's some obvious reason for why this is happening but I'm at a loss. Why are my pictures coming out purple?

*Using a Sony Xperia Z camera phone*

**EXAMPLE**
[image: Example of purple embers]

Comment: is it only fire or all bright and clipped highlights?

Comment: Just fire so far @MichaelNielsen

Comment: I realize this has been solved, but any chance you could post a sample image.  I'm really curious what it looks like and it would make it easier for those unfamiliar with the problem to see what's happening.

Comment: No worries @AJHenderson, I deleted most of them but I kept the one I've attached as I thought it looked kinda cool :D

Comment: Oh wow, that's crazy.  I've honestly never seen a camera do that before, but then again, I'd be a little upset if my high end DSLR didn't have a good IR filter and I don't think I've ever thought to point my smartphone at a fire before.  Now I'm curious to try though.

Comment: this makes me think that phone has NO IR filter at all!!

Comment: Is there any way of finding out? I doubt it has one, but I've been surprised several times by the range of features it has (mind you that's technically the features the built in camera software has)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are seeing is Infra-Red (AKA 'IR')

The sensor (probably) has an IR filter, but strong sources such as fire can still get through, and show up as a light purple on most CCD / CMOS sensors.

Comment: Thanks Darkcat. Is there any way to counter it (short of PhotoShop)?

Comment: not really - the only method i can think of is to find some sort of extra IR filter and put it over you lens. You could possibly get one off a dead camera sensor.

Comment: that wouldnt fit. on thorlabs and edmundoptics you can find IR cut filters in all sizes mounted and unmounted.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen - yes it would, use blu-tak.

Comment: are you talking about putting in on the sensor or the lens?

Comment: ah, just noted that we are talking about a camera phone, lol :)

Comment: Well, you can get stick on lense for camera phones so I'm hoping I can get a filter that way

Comment: @CLockeWork - its highly unlikely you'll find a ready-made IR filter for your phone tbh...

Comment: @DarkcatStudios, yeah it's sure looking that way; fish-eye lenses, wide angle lenses, even tripods... but no IR filters. Oh well, I'll have to get a real camera soon enough anyway, though this one is surprisingly comprehensive :D